# Combining multiple facebook page reviews feeds in one call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How is it possible that I can add another access token to this call that references the second id I would like to retrieve reviews from.

In all other instances like posts, photos etc this would work but because you are required to have a page access token to retrieve the data for reviews I'm not sure how to construct the url to make the call. Is it possible?

https://graph.facebook.com/ratings?ids=slickremix,reformavi&field=rating&limit=5&access_token=EAAP9hArvboQBAN5...

That call returns something like this, as you can see the second id reformavi is not returning data.

```
{
   "slickremix": {
      "data": [
         {
            "created_time": "2016-10-13T09:22:02+0000",
            "reviewer": {
               "name": "Jens Kranen",
               "id": "10211267740634296"
            },
            "rating": 5,
            "review_text": "Fantastic customer support. Very quick response. Spencer could identify the problem within minutes and gave great advice.\nThank you"
         },
         {
            "created_time": "2016-10-07T14:22:19+0000",
            "reviewer": {
               "name": "Marc McHale",
               "id": "10157614348555341"
            }
            "rating": 5,
            "review_text": "I purchased the Facebook Reviews plugin for a client website and both my client and I are very happy with the appearance and functionality! Plus, the customer service was outstanding!"
         }
      ],
      "paging": {
         "cursors": {
            "before": "MTM4MjkwMTM4ODoxMTg3OTA3NTE1MjU4ODQZD",
            "after": "MTI1MTQ3Njk2NToxMTg3OTA3NTE1MjU4ODQZD"
         },
         "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/118790751525884/ratings?access_token=EAAP9hArvboQBAN5HpnbA5m87qC7poAAqB0YS47zxBCBmCfVRcqCC7zX1XDNCv6cSe3KFnMtPVysUms0MuXLxWfv8D9McMwzvD2HWWd0IO6FOZC6ogvcta8FWZBR0vUA9HCZAdqdB53fyUB26XLb76ORLspiPg3Hzb4Pn5RTjwZDZD&pretty=1&limit=5&after=MTI1MTQ3Njk2NToxMTg3OTA3NTE1MjU4ODQZD"
      }
   },
   "reformavi": {
      "data": [

      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: You can not pass two different access tokens in one API call. If you are looking to reduce the number of HTTP requests, then look into batch requests.

Comment: Kinda what I figured, but had to throw the question out there. Thanks for confirming. Funny how the ids= instance is even allowed here since it's not possible to add another token.